# Magento2.3: How to hide static block-widget from specific page?

Tags: magento2.3.2, static-block, widgets

1. I have created one widget by creating a static block.
2. My widget options are set to show on All pages. It's working fine.
3. Now I need to hide that static block from the Checkout page, Cart page and contact us page only. For all remaining pages, The same as earlier.
4. My static block's identifier is `1800_popup`

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi ! I try to do the exact same thing, did you find how to do it ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is the file you need to override module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

below is a reference to remove static-block, add in body tag with parent reference block

```
<referenceBlock name="content.top"/>
    <referenceBlock name="contact-us-info" remove="true"/>
</referenceBlock>
```